Find the path of a vertex of an equilateral triangle with a moving vertex
Point A(a,0), point B(0,a), and point C is a point on line segment AB. Connecting OC such that ∠BOC=15 Degree. Point M is a moving point on line AB, constructing an equilateral triangle OMN with OM as a side. Connect CN, what is the minimum value of CN?
The key point should be to find the path of N when point M is moving. The challenge is what is the path of N when point M is moving along AB. It seems to be a straight line, but I cannot prove it so far.
This problem can be refined into: M is a moving point on line segment AB of an isosceles right triangle. Constructing an equilateral triangle OMN with OM as a side. Connect CN, what is the path of N when M is moving?
Thank you very much!


What have you tried? What did you discover? Where are you having trouble? What is challenging about that?

@PaulTanenbaum, I think the trouble is to prove the condition under which CN achieves its min

@PaulTanenbaum, the challenge is what is the path of N when point M is moving along AB. It seems to be a straight line, but I cannot prove it so far. I guess the min CN would be obtained when point M coincides with C, and the min length of CN would be equal to OC. But this intuition is incorrect.

It's a straight line parallel to $OC$.

@Intelligentipauca i believe u are correct. Could you give some hints for proof? Thank you!

Ok I may be wrong here so forgive me but here is what I did based off what you've said.
So there is a moving vector M and you need the path of N as M moves.
First I got a vector line connecting A and B
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + x\begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$$
where x is a scalar constant. the point is B and the direction is BA so as x gets larger M moves left and up.
then from what you said the triangle OMN is equilateral therefore the angle MON must be $$\frac{\pi}{3}$$ so we can preform a matrix transformation of pi/3 radians clockwise to get the vector of N in terms of x. So N =>
$$ N = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} && -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} && \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix} 4-4x \\ 4x \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 - 2x(1 + \sqrt{3}) \\ 2 + 2x( 1 - \sqrt{3}) \end{pmatrix}$$
so this (I think, may have made a mistake lmao) is the path of N as M varies. again not 100% sure if this is what you want but this is how I read your question. did you need it in a cartesian form or is vector form ok? also what is the significance of the line CN if you're only interested in the locus of N. Not sure if this exactly answers your question but I tried my best! have a good day :)

Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our quality standard policy. Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

@Michael thank you very much. Apart from a small typo in your transform matrix, your method is helpful. Yes, in a cartesian form will be better. This is just a competition-level question. I am not aware of the special significance of CN.
